# why are my hair strands coming from the bottom of my donut and not the top

Tags: particles

why are these hair strands coming from the bottom and not at the top of the icing[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, click on the icing and go to edit mode. There, select whichever parts you want the hair/particles to be on. Go to particle settings and click assign. I would reccomend selecting the whole upperside of the icing for the particles to be there but that is your choice.